# Logo Image not showing on report from SSRS, getting the error "the underlying connection was closed an unexpected error occurred on a send"

Tags: reporting-services

I've got 2 sites running on different machines and each have their SQL on a separate machine. The reports have an image said of imgLogo which gets defined on the site and is grabbed when the report is generated.

In both reports, the data comes into the report fine but on one of them it doesn't return an image and i instead get this red x where the image should be and in the log is the error

```
processing!ReportServer_0-1!27cc!03/29/2022-13:48:41:: w WARN: An error occurred retrieving the external resource 'https://site_name/__files/publicdoc/2374123/file.png' : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
```

Now i've compared the report servers on both machines and cannot see any difference there and the actual reports themselves run fine.

I've tried looking into TLS but honestly I'm lost so any help would be appreciated

Tried:

- specifying an execution account
- lowering the SecureConnectionLevel in ReportServer.config file
- Looking into TLS (although i don't understand this)

Comment: Although I don't know what the issue is, you could try logging into the two servers running SSRS and simply open a browser with the url of the image as stated in the error log and see if you can access the image on both servers as expected.

Comment: @AlanSchofield yep, can access it fine from the servers than run SSRS by going via direct link like the error gave me